# When using [!set] zsh invokes history expansion

Tags: zsh

When I am searching for a file with

```
ls [a-t]est.txt
```

it gives the result `test.txt` as expected

However, when I use

```
ls [!a-g]est.txt
```

output is `ls [aptg]est.txt`

Some other examples for [!set]:

- `ls [!b-z]est.txt` returns `[bbz]est.txt`
- `ls [!g-h]est.txt` returns `ls [git clone --depth=1h]est.txt`

Is there something wrong with my zsh, or does [!set] works differently in zsh?

---

Machine is Linux Mint 18.2

Comment: Try `^` in place of `!` for negation - it looks like `!` is invoking a command history expansion (at least in the interactive shell)

Comment: Yes! That is it. Do you know why `!` is (by the looks) invoking a command history expansion? And how do you know how to restore this?

Comment: See [How to disable a zsh special variable (bang tilde !~)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21236112/4440445)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to avoid history expansion is to quote `!` a backslash:

```
ls [\!a-g]est.txt
```

Of course when negating a set it is probably easier to just use `^` instead of `!`.

Another way is to temporarily disable history expansion by adding the character sequence `!"` anywhere (really!) before the (previously) first `!`. `!"` will be removed and any subsequent `!` have no special meaning.

```
!" ls [!a-g]est.txt
ls !" [!a-g]est.txt
ls [!"!a-g]est.txt
l!"s [!a-g]est.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

As proposed by steeldriver, `^` in place of `!` makes [!set] resolves the issue.

Reason for this is that in zsh `!` triggers the history expansion. If you do not want this to happen, disable the history expansion. For this, execute `setopt nobanghist` in the command line.